# Build / deploy an app that works with an assembly even when the assembly version changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-assembly

I have an application and 3 Office Add-ins which all use an assembly registered in the GAC.

The problem I have is that if I update my application and the assembly to a new version, then the office add-ins no longer work.  They complain they cannot find the assembly anymore.

Is there something I can enter in my visual studio project so that it will also use a newer version of the assembly even though it was not built with it?

Am I correct that if the assembly version number Major / Minor numbers don't change then the office add-ins should work?  For example if I had 2.0.0.0 and then the next version was 2.0.1.0 then this should not "break" my Office Addins.

Comment: That's not correct, all 4 values matter.  Just don't remove the old version from the GAC so the add-ins can continue to use the old version.  Use Fuslogvw.exe if you still have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Go in the solution explorer open the references node and select properties on the dll. 
In the properties there is a setting called "spezific version". Set this to false and it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not the suggestion will work. See this explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022134/how-exactly-does-the-specific-version-property-of-an-assembly-reference-work-i?lq=1