# Assembly reference version numbers are confusing. Lastest verison is 3.2.3.0, so why do all references say 3.0.0.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, assembly-resolution

### VS Project Assembly Reference Inconsistency

I have System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll version *3.2.3.0* installed via NuGet.  When I open References in VisualStudio project explorer and look at the properties window for that reference, it says version *3.0.0.0*.  Likewise, System.Web.WebPages.dll is displaying version *3.0.0.0* in spite of having version *3.2.3.0* installed.  If I open the *.csproj file, the reference is `<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0` but it has a child node that says: `<HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>`

So, first of all, why does it seem to be referenced everywhere as Version 3.0.0.0, while the NuGet package claims it's 3.2.3.0 and the reference has a hint path pointing to that specific assembly. Is Microsoft publishing different subversions of the same assembly... all with the same version number (3.0.0.0)?

I thought perhaps it has something to do with the "Specific Version" option being set to false, but then I see other referenced DLLs such as System.Web.Mvc displaying version 5.2.3.0, in spite of also having "Specific Version" set to false.  Why this difference?

### web.config Assembly Reference Inconsistency

Meanwhile, in the web.config file, the `system.web.webPages.razor` section references `host` and `pages` element types in the `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` assembly with version *3.0.0.0*, even thought the NuGet package says it's version *3.2.3.0*.

Similar to the hintpath in the *.csproj file, the web.config file has an entry under `configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly` for `System.Web.WebPages` which a contains child element `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.2.3.0" />`.

In any case, it seems like every update of `System.Web.WebPages.dll` and `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll` (but not `System.Web.Mvc.dll`?) keeps the same version number (3.0.0.0), but then uses hintpaths and binding redirects to locate a specific subversion.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point is that some references (a dozen of NuGet packages) need version 3.1.X.X while others use 3.2.X.X, and another one uses 3.0.X.X, etc. They almost never have the exact same version referenced. The exposed code base (signatures) doesn't change over releases, there are just some bug fixes.

By using binding redirections there is no need for a (very) specific version of the assembly version to be set anywhere. The latest version (the version set in the `newversion` in the assembly binding redirect) is used. All done. Run!

Comment: That makes sense, but something's still not right. `newversion` specifies a number that doesn't exist, because every version of the assembly downloaded from NuGet (e.g. package version 3.2.3.0), actually has a version number of 3.0.0.0 embedded in the DLL, which is visible in the properties of the project reference. Does the binding redirect's `newversion` attribute actually have an invalid value? I may have changed it at some point, not realizing only 3.0.0.0 is valid. Or is the 3.2.3.0 version number associated with the DLL in some way other than what's displayed in its properties?

Comment: The problem is there's nothing documenting this behavior.  These projects really need to say "We compile all our updates with a single major build version number, and they should be referenced as such.  The version in NuGet is a fake number that's meaningless to your code."  Anyway, I'm assuming 3.0.0.0 is the only valid version number, so I'm correcting my bindingRedirect to use a newVersion of 3.0.0.0 instead of 3.2.3.0.

Comment: I don't have an environment to check now, but will take a look tomorrow regarding your first comment.

Comment: This answer is also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24022135/88409 The "SpecificVersion" property of the reference in VisualStudio is a compile time check.  It looks for the assembly in the `hintPath` first, so that takes priority, then the project output directory, and finally the GAC.