# How do I reference a DLL in my C# but not a specific version?

Tags: c#

I've got different versions of toolkits from a supplier, when I've built my app with an earlier version I cannot just simply swap out the DLL for the later version as my application complains and throws errors.

It's not an issue with the functionality of the toolkit as if I remove the older version and add the newer one without any further changes I can compile it and it will work with the newer version.

Comment: Which errors? Is it a signed assembly?

Answer (score 2):

Edit your csproj and add `<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>` in the reference xml node.

```
<Reference Include="Foo, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\Bar\Foo.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Here's a great explanation (from which I took the above sample): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24022135/578843