# In CMake, how to set a C# project's external references to specific versions?

Tags: c#, cmake

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and CMake 3.15.4 for a C# / Windows form project, which requires a handful of external references. I set them up in the following way:

```
set_property(TARGET my_exe PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
    ${dependency_1}
    ${dependency_2}
    ${dependency_3})

set_property(TARGET my_exe PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_${dependency_1}
    "path_to_dependency_1")

...
```

I notice that under the **Properties** menu of each dependency, the property **Specific Version** is always set to `False` by default. I'm wondering how I could set it to `True` in CMake script to make the target use certain version of dependencies. Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_<refname>` [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_refname.html) does not mention version. But, although not officially supported by CMake, it is possible to force the `SpecificVersion` reference property to `True`.

There is a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24022135/3987854) documenting the situations in which the Specific Version will be checked. The check is influenced by the *presence of version information in the assembly reference*, and the *presence of the `<SpecificVersion>` element*. See the table reproduced here:

```
                            |     Version information
                            |  Present       Not present
----------------------------+------------------------------
<SpecificVersion>           |
- Present, has value True   |    Yes (1)        Yes (check always fails) (2)
- Present, has value False  |    No  (3)        No (4)
- Not present               |    Yes (5)        No (6)
```

Because the CMake Visual Studio generators don't provide a mechanism (yet) to set the `<SpecificVersion>` reference property, we have to force the Specific Version check by inserting version information along with the reference name (case 5 in the table above). Try something like this:

```
set_property(TARGET my_exe PROPERTY 
    "VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_Dependency1, Version=2.1.1"
    "path_to_dependency_1"
)
```

This will set the version to `2.1.1`, and the **Specific Version** reference property will be set to `True`, instead of the default value of `False`.