# ServerManager.OpenRemote error 80040154 CLSID {2b72133b-3f5b-4602-8952-803546ce3344} in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a console app, which is using Microsoft.Web.Administration to remotely manage IIS on remote server (I used this [Credentials for ServerManager.OpenRemote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458410/credentials-for-servermanager-openremote) - modified ahadmin properties, opened TCP port 135. I also used impersonation). Everything works fine - I can remotely create Sites and App Pools and so on.

But when I'm trying to do the same thing in ASP.NET MVC 4 app, I get this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class
>   factory for remote component with CLSID
>   {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine "remoteServerIP"
>   failed due to the following error: 80040154 "remoteServerIP".

I know many people get this error, and I saw a lot of posts about it, but nothing worked for me. I tried switching my MVC app to platform target X86 ([Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t?rq=1)), on remote machine I enabled full permissions for both HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{2b72133b-3f5b-4602-8952-803546ce3344} and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{2b72133b-3f5b-4602-8952-803546ce3344} for the account that I'm using to impersonate.
The problem seems to be in some difference between MVC and console apps, but I can't figure out what it is.

I'm on Windows 7 x64, remote server - windows server 2008 R2 x64. There's IIS 7.5 on both machines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution. The issue was the fact that my MVC app was using a wrong version of Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll.

When I was debugging console app, I was able to get a list of sites from local IIS using this code

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
```

and a list of sites from remote IIS using this code

```
ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("remoteServerIpAddress");
```

and everything was OK.
Then I put exactly the same code in an MVC app, and when I tried to get a list of sites from remote IIS I got the exception from the question.
When trying to get a list of sites from local IIS, I got websites from IIS Express. Server Manager seemed to connect to IIS Express instead of full IIS, but I didn't pay much attention to this at first. Unfortunately.

Accidentally I found this post [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager looking in wrong directory for IISExpress applicationHost.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208270/microsoft-web-administration-servermanager-looking-in-wrong-directory-for-iisexp), from where I found out that

> If the application, in which you are using
>   Microsoft.Web.Administration ..., is running on
>   IISExpress, it will always fallback to Microsoft.Web.Administration
>   version 7.9.0.0 due to an assembly redirect in the aspnet.config in
>   the IIS express.

I was using IIS Express to debug, and it redirected me to wrong version of Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll - 7.9.0.0, and I needed 7.0.0.0, which is used by full IIS.
So I hosted my MVC app on full local IIS, debugged it there and it worked! I successfully retrieved a list of sites from remote IIS. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much! This was driving me bonkers!

Comment: same problem but with the .net-core microsoft.web.administration package thinking it was the right one to use